# Fourier Transform-Time stamped data and Linear Regression

Tags: regression, time-series, fourier-transform, minitab

I am new to **DFT (Discrete Fourier Transform)**, but I am trying to use it to decompose my traffic volume data into two vectors (x,y i.e. independent and dependent variables). Afterwards I can apply a **Linear Regression** for forecasting.

I have historical minute by minute traffic flow data. I want to develop a model that forecasts future values based on the historical data. To solve this I want to use Linear Regression. My input variable ($x_1$, $x_2$, ...$x_n$) are designed using some statistical methods and I have an $n * m$ matrix for my Regression Model input.

How can I get the y (i.e. response variable) for my historical record? Can **FFT (Fast Fourier Transform)** can help me in that by transforming my historical data. If yes, how can FFT help